# suppress lot/lof entry in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Using the caption package, one can suppress lot/lof entry with an empty optional argument for \caption.
But the caption package is incompatible with memoir. How can I suppress lot/lof entries in memoir?

Comment: The `caption` pacakge is not incompatible with `memoir`, works just fine with it. `memoir` issues a warning telling users that when they use `caption`, `memoir`'s own interface for configuring captions will no longer have any affect.

Comment: The problem is: I'm working on my ctable package, which has an option cap= to set the entry for lot/lof. If it't empty, no entry should be made, like in the caption package. I can, of course \RequirePackage{caption} in ctable, but that would deprive memoir+ctable users of memoir's own caption facilities.

Comment: There are pros and cons. I do it myself in one of my packages, require `caption, because it can do stuff that `memoir` will not get close to any time soon. Plus I use `caption` for all my projects, eventhough I maintain `memoir`

Comment: Why not make some of these features plugable, such that users can change them, think of callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for all comments - I finally decided not to \Require caption inside ctable but let it to the user to  do so. If he uses an empty cap option a warning will be issued suggesting caption inclusion.

Comment: Still, I would like to suggest that memoir should not enter empty captions into lot/lof, just like the caption package - it makes no sense to make such an entry.

Comment: I agree, I'll add it to the todo list. I'd also like to have the `caption` feature where the delim disapears if the caption is empty. Reliably testing for empty arg is not easy without `etoolbox`. Well, some people seems to use the empty arg `feature`, so it needs to be configurable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After **daleif**'s comment, you can use the `caption` package and its `list=no` option:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

test text

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{list=no}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption{A numbered and named caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption*{An unnumbered and unnamed caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, within `memoir`, is to use `\legend` or `\namedlegend`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

test text

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\legend{A unnumbered and unnamed caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\namedlegend{A unnumbered but named caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\stepcounter{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\legend{\figurename~\thefigure: A named and numbered caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to define a command to change the `lotdepth` counter (`lofdepth`, in the case of figures) typeset the caption using the standard `\caption` command and then restoring the default value for the counter:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand\NLcaption[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\setcounter{lotdepth}{0}}%
  \caption{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\setcounter{lotdepth}{1}}}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
Test text
\begin{table}
\NLcaption{Test caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my comment to daleif above. I can, of course detect memoir and then use \legend instead of \caption, but it's argument would probably have to be more complicated than "\figurename~\thefigure: "? For example, the : would not honor any setting of \captiondelim.

Comment: @WyboDekker yes, obviously the label used in my example has to use `\captiondelim` (and other settings). I've added a new option to my answer providing another possibility that will honor the settings for standard captions.